# Update a value into a json file in PHP

Tags: php, json

Supposing I have the following json file:

```
{
    "infos": {
        "name": "Logo changed."
    },
    "datas": [
        {...}
    ]
}
```

---

I want to change the value of `name`.

So, I tried this:

```
$to_replace = 'New logo change.'    
$datas['infos']['name'][0] = $to_replace;
```

But after that my json looks bad:

```
{
    "infos": {
        "0": {
            "name": "New logo change."
        },
        "name": "Logo changed."
    },
    "datas": [
        {...}
    ]
}
```

---

Why it doesn't work please ?

Thanks.

Comment: Just drop the `[0]`: `$datas['infos']['name'] = $to_replace;` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `[0]`, you don't need it:

```
$datas['infos']['name'] = $to_replace;
```

PHP actually thinks you have a `"0"` in a `name` item so added one there for you.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$to_replace = 'New logo change.'    
$datas['infos']['name'][0] = $to_replace;
```

With

```
$to_replace = 'New logo change.'    
$datas['infos']['name'] = $to_replace;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code (without the `[0]`)

```
$to_replace = 'New logo change.'    
$datas['infos']['name'] = $to_replace;
```

In PHP, for a JSON object, if you use a number, it will used **as a new key** and not for the "first element"